# Haven't found or didn't find?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

I was searching for something and I didn't find it. So I would say to my friend:

> I searched for it but I didn't find it.

or

> I've searched but haven't found it.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6):

**TL/DR:**

> I haven't found it.

Implies you will keep looking, as in *I haven't found it...yet.*

> I didn't find it.

Implies that you will not continue the search.

Answer (score 1):

There are three aspects to consider, when it comes to the decision present perfect versus simple past.

1. Is there a signal word for one of the two candidates?
2. Is the action finished?
3. Do you want to emphasize the consequences of the action to present?

> I searched for something but I didn't find anything.

There are no signal words, the actions are completely finished and there is maybe a consequence to the present, i.e. you were not able to find your wallet, so you'll have to ask someone for money.

> I have searched for something but I haven't found it.

There are no signal words, actions are finished, so perfect seems not the best choice.

Here is my proposal:

> I searched for my keys in the morning, unfortunately I haven't found them yet.

In the first part of the sentence, you have signal word for the past tense (time) and in the second part for the present perfect (yet).

NOTE: I am neither a native speaker nor an expert - I am just trying to help!

Comment: I'm only a native speaker, and have never seen the rule set out in the way you have done. I just learned how to say these things at my mother's knee. But I am very impressed with the rationale you have given - and it produces the correct answers too.

Comment: What if I said " I've been searching for something" so the second part should be" but I haven't found anything" or "I didn't find anything"?

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish between past simple and present perfect simple tenses, you have to be aware about three important points here, which are :

1. **The time in which an action happened; at a certain time in the past (even if it was just a few seconds ago) or that an action has just happened?**

For example: *I phoned him 5 minutes ago. //  I have just phoned him.*

2. **Whether an action took place at a particular time in the past or how often an action has happened and somehow continued till the present.**

For example: *I visited London last October. //  I have been to London for some time* (-> means that I went to  London and I'm back now)

3. **Emphasis on action or result?; to express what happened in the past! Or to show the result that comes up with that action ( the consequence of the past's action in the present).**

For example: *I bought a car.  (Just telling what I did it ) //  I have bought a car ( I want to express what I did and expect your reflection on that).*